# Character Encoding in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, encoding, perl

I have UTF8 data stored in Postgres.  I can query it with a Perl script and display it properly.  When I use the Postgres client, it displays like the encoding is off.  I'll see characters displayed like \u0087\u0081.

From inside the database:

```
=> \encoding
UTF8
```

In the shell (I manually set LANGUAGE as I read elsewhere that might be a fix.):

```
$locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

This is in Ubuntu 16.04.

What setting have I missed?

Edited to add code populating psql:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

### Source DB setup
my $maria_database="srcdb";
my $maria_user = "";
my $maria_password = "";
my $maria_host= "localhost";

my $mariadbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:database=$maria_database;host=$maria_host","$maria_user","$maria_password",{AutoCommit=>1,RaiseError=>1,PrintError=>0,mysql_enable_utf8=>1});

my $mysrcquery = "SELECT fields from sourcetable limit 2;";
my $src = $mariadbh->prepare($mysrcquery);

### Destination DB setup
my $postgresql_database="desdb";
my $postgresql_user="";
my $postgresql_password="";
my $postgresql_host="localhost";

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:Pg:dbname=$postgresql_database; host=$postgresql_host", "$postgresql_user", "$postgresql_password", {AutoCommit => 0,pg_enable_utf8 => 1});

my $pginsertquery = "insert into desttable (fields) VALUES (?)";
my $pginsert = $dbh->prepare($pginsertquery);

$src->execute();
my ($col0);
$src->bind_columns(undef, \$col0 );

### Loop through results and insert in to psql
while($src->fetch())
{
  print $col0;
  $pginsert->execute($col0);
}

$dbh->commit;
$dbh-> disconnect or warn "Disconnection failed: DBI::errstr\n";
$mariadbh-> disconnect or warn "Disconnection failed: DBI::errstr\n";
```

Test sqldump:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 9.6.1
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 9.6.1

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

--
-- Name: test; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: testuser
--

CREATE TABLE test (
    testdata text
);


ALTER TABLE test OWNER TO testuser;

--
-- Name: test id; Type: DEFAULT; Schema: public; Owner: testuser
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY test ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('test_id_seq'::regclass);


--
-- Data for Name: test; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: testuser
--

COPY test (testdata) FROM stdin;
Ð¿Ñ<80>Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ<82>Ñ<81>Ñ<82>Ð²Ñ<83>Ñ<8e>
\.


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

Comment: Can you show us the Perl script to insert the data into the database? My assumption is that perl is inserting non-utf8 data (because working with utf8 in perl is a PITA). That PostgreSQL assumes it's utf8, but that the terminal has no idea of how to display it, becuase it's not utf8.

Comment: Unset `pg_enable_utf8`. This should never bet set to 1. If your client encoding is right it'll do that anyway. This is making the driver *assume* (needlessly) that everything is stored in utf8, and that the client encoding is utf8. This is a bad assumption and can sting you and may be what's happening.

Comment: Same thing with `mysql_enable_utf8` these flags are forcing the driver to make assumptions that it probably should not be making. You're setting `SvUTF_on` on everything and wondering why all these assumptions don't hold true across multiple databases. And we still have no idea what's in MySQL.

Comment: Edited to add test sql dump.  That was created with mysql_enable_utf8 enabled (because without it my Perl script won't even display the data) but without pg_enable_utf8.  The included record should display, "приветствую" and it does so if I extract it with a Perl script without pg_enable_utf8.

Comment: That's not Unicode though.  Clearly. So if that's in your database, then whatever put it there put something that's not Unicode. You can see `pg_dump` is connecting with client_encoding = utf8, and it's still putting that crap out. So the problem then is in whatever is inserting into Pg. Not whatever is outputting from Pg.

Comment: Make sure your MySQL is storing in utf8, http://stackoverflow.com/q/1049728/124486

Comment: using mysql connect and output `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM sourcetable;` if that shows up as anything but utf8 perhaps you need to [migrate to utf8](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6115612/124486)

Comment: Source column is utf8_general_mysql500_ci.  My research earlier on this showed that MariaDB isn't as flexible as psql in utf8 and that it sometimes uses utf8mb4.

Comment: I would try updating the MySQL DBD Driver to the development version, do that confirm with `perl -MDBD::MySQL\ 9999` that you're running the development version, unset `mysql_enable_utf8` from the connection string and see if it works.

Comment: I'm looking at how to update dbd::mysql to experimental.  If I'm already parsing the data in Perl before inserting it in to psql, would it make more sense for me to just reencode it differently inside Perl?  I don't have plans to use MariaDB again.

Comment: Perl only knows one thing, is it or is it not utf8. That's the only flag. So if it's not utf8, perl is just going to dump it to the terminal as if it were bytes. If the terminal renders it (is not in utf8) that's fine.. It'll work.. for the terminal. But, PostgreSQL is only going to accept utf8. So if it's not utf8, you have decode it from whatever it is to unicode, and encode it back in utf8 in perl.

Comment: Did any of this work?

Comment: Hi Evan.  So sorry for my slow response.  It turned out to be an issue with a proprietary module used in the Perl script that I didn't include as I sanitized the code that I posted.  It was double encoding the data before inserting in to Postgres.  I really appreciate your help.  What's the appropriate way for me to give you credit for your effort to help me and to not mislead others if they stumble across this?  Regardless, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`\u0087` ([END OF SELECTED AREA](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0087/index.htm)) and `\u0081` are control characters in the LATIN-1 block. Displaying them as `\u0087\u0081` is in fact the convention, and it seems to be what your terminal is doing.

Can you show us the Perl script to insert the data into the database? My assumption is that Perl is inserting non-utf8 data because working with utf8 in perl is a PITA. That PostgreSQL assumes it's utf8 and that the terminal has no idea of how to display it, becuase it's

- not really utf8, just marked up as utf8.
- or, you have legitimate control characters encoded in your utf8.

Be careful if you used `utf8::upgrade` or the like which sets the flag without decoding from the original format.

## Advice

### Update DBD::Pg, DBD::mysql

First update both DBD::Pg, and DBD::mysql

```
cpan DBD::Pg DBD::mysql
```

### Bug in DBD::mysql

Reviewing change logs, DBD::mysql has always had a bug, you may even want to install the development version ([DBD-mysql-4.041_01](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/MICHIELB/DBD-mysql-4.041_01/lib/DBD/mysql.pm))..

```
2016-12-12 Patrick Galbraith, Michiel Beijen, DBI/DBD community (4.041_1)
* Unicode fixes: when using mysql_enable_utf8 or mysql_enable_utf8mb4,
  previous versions of DBD::mysql did not properly encode input statements
  to UTF-8 and retrieved columns were always UTF-8 decoded regardless of the
  column charset.
  Fix by Pali Rohár.
  Reported and feedback on fix by Marc Lehmann
  (https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=87428)
  Also, the UTF-8 flag was not set for decoded data:
  (https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=53130)
```

Who knows what the hell they're doing there. Unicode is complex and it's not surprising that MySQL developers and users don't understand it.

### Unsetting assumptions

I would unset `pg_enable_utf8` and `mysql_enable_utf8`. Pretend these options exist. You're force-setting a utf8 flag on the internal variable. You probably don't want to do that. You clearly can't ensure everything is utf8, or it'd be working properly. Time to remove assumptions. Not create more assumptions.

We need a sample case. You claim foreign characters are displaying as Unicode escape sequences, but you only present control-characters (which can't be displayed). Perhaps you can simply this whole thing, and dump the table `pg_dump -t <Table>` or copy the problematic rows into a temp table and dump that. Then we can review that data and see what we've got.

Comment: Thanks Evan.  I'm pulling data from a MariaDB instance to insert in to Postgres.  The results of the MariaDB select query didn't display correctly in the terminal until I added, "mysql_enable_utf8=>1" to the connect string.  My test script does a select query against Postgres and displays properly through STDOUT.  It's just the Postgres client that doesn't display the data as I would expect.  The sample characters I posted were just a small subset.  The English character I am trying to store display correctly.  Foreign language characters are displaying with the \u#### the PG client.

Comment: DBD::Pg assumes `client_encoding` is set to utf8. Have you verified this is so? What version of DBD::Pg are you using, and what version of PostgreSQL? And, what is your DBD::Pg version. run this `perl -MDBD::Pg\ 99999 -e1`.

Comment: DBD::mysql is 4.0330

Comment: DBD::Pg is 3.5.3.  I've used this command to make sure client_encoding was set:  set client_encoding to 'UTF8';.  Postgres version =  PostgreSQL 9.6.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 5.3.1 20160413, 64-bit

Comment: Where did you use that command? Inside of perl after you connected? Or through psql?

Comment: I ran the client_encoding command inside psql.  Perl displays the data perfectly.  The code I added to my original post is neutered but includes all of the psql interaction.

Comment: Setting client_encoding from inside psql does not set it from inside perl. It may default to `utf8`, but that's for the session only. (psql and perl must always be two separate db sessions)